# Географические названия, в которых буква "э" стоит НЕ на первом месте

Tags: ономастика, названия, топонимика, транслитерация, буква

Проблема употребления "э" в русском языке — тема непростая, хотя я лично не понимаю, зачем при транслитерации, когда в иностранном языке отчётливо слышится "э", частенько меняют на "е". Бедная "э", мне её всегда жалко так же, как "ё" (которую порой заменяют на "йо", хотя это не всегда точно передаёт иностранную речь, а в русскоязычных словах "ё" вообще порой игнорируют, что вносит неразбериху в произношение и сводит с ума иностранцев). Ведь не зря нам дан именно такой алфавит, надо использовать все его возможности, считаю...

Но вопрос в другом. Какие вы знаете *географические* названия, в которых есть буква "э" (в любом месте, *только не первая*)? Особенно интересны случаи, в которых топоним оканчивается на "э" или "э" с любой буквой — хоть гласной, хоть согласной ("...эа", "...эо", "...эи", "...эм", "...эт", "...эк" и т. д.)? Можно реальные устоявшиеся, можно вымышленные, которые встречаются в литературе. Что угодно из топонимов: страны, города, деревни, моря, реки, озёра, горы, острова, леса и прочее и прочее. Чем названия разнообразнее, тем лучше (бывает, что несколько начинаются одинаково: "Уэст-..."). Составные названия наподобие Марий Эл не годятся, если в них с "э" начинается одно из слов (и других "э" в нём нет).
Если название вымышленное, пожалуйста, обязательно укажите источник. К реальному названию тоже желательно указать коротенькую справку (что это и где это находится).

Интересно, наберётся ли хотя бы штук 50...

Сам навскидку нашёл несколько:

- **Кэмпбелл** (архипелаг в Новой Зеландии и множество одноимённых округов в США);
- **Уэст-Йоркшир** (графство в Англии, одно из нескольких, начинающихся с "Уэст");
- **Карлсруэ** (город в Германии).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Почему не надо жалеть букву Э?**

Это буква с ограниченными возможностями, но никто не притесняет ее намеренно.

1. **Краткая история буквы Э**

Буква Э (так называемое «Э оборотное») –  сравнительно «молодая» буква в русском алфавите: она появилась лишь в XVIII веке, вскоре после установления гражданской азбуки, при этом, по сравнению с буквой Е, она стала обозначать чистый, нейотированный звук.

**Первоначальное назначение Э** – употребление **в начале слова или после гласных**  в заимствованных словах (поэт) и в иноязычных собственных именах (Эдисон, Суэц). Несмотря на неприятие этой буквы некоторыми писателями и учеными, она не только закрепилась в русской графике, но и пишется сейчас **после согласных** в некоторых заимствованных словах (мэр, рэп, пленэр).

В исконно русских словах  **нет твердого  звука Э.** Твердое произношение гласного Э характерно для заимствованных слов. Написание Э после согласных **непривычно для русской графики,** поэтому такое слово всегда выглядит чужим.

2. **Как происходит заимствование иноязычных слов**

Заимствованное слово в языке в начальный период обычно **произносится с твердым Э** и как бы примеряет для себя письменную форму Э или Е. Окончательный выбор зависит от многих причин (фонетических и графических).

В некоторых случаях (достаточно редко) письменная форма Э закрепляется в языке (как и твердое произношение), в других – пишется только  Е, а произношение гласного может меняться от твердого к мягкому. В заключение делается и этот выбор – слово окончательно **вписывается** в фонетическую и графическую систему языка.

Именно **подобные колебания**  при выборе фонетической формы заимствованных слов не позволяют **навести строгий порядок** в написании букв Э и Е, а также в произношении соответствующих им звуков.

3. **Когда пишется буква Э**

Буква Э пишется **в начале слова и после гласных:**
этот, экран, эпитет, эра, эта,  этикет – в начале слова, маэстро, поэма, менуэт – после гласных.
Но: проект, проекция, траектория, реестр, аудиенция, реквием, иероглиф.  Здесь произносится не мягкий, а «смягченный» вариант звука Э.

Буква Э  после твёрдых согласных пишется **в мало обрусевших словах** иноязычного происхождения: пэр, сэр, мэр, пленэр, рэкет, фэнтези.
Но обычно **Е заменяет Э**: адекватный, альтернатива, антенна и др. В случае затруднения следует уточнить выбор мягкого или твердого варианта чтения буквы Е по словарю.

4. **Некоторые примеры географических названий**

В этой теме буква Э встречается значительно чаще, что связано с необходимостью точной записи названий, особенно в малоизвестных именах.

Вероятно, таких примеров не так уж мало.

***Мэ́риленд*** — небольшой по территории штат на востоке США,

***Лэнгли*** — невключённая территория (фактически — район) в статистически обособленной местности Маклин в округе Фэрфакс в штате Виргиния, США.

***Пуэ́рто-Ри́ко*** (исп. Puerto Rico — «богатый порт»), официально — Свобо́дно ассоции́рованное госуда́рство Пуэ́рто-Ри́ко.

***Руэда***, винный регион Испании

***Суэ́цкий кана́л*** — бесшлюзовый судоходный канал в Египте

Ледник ***Туэйтса*** — ледник в Западной Антарктиде, известный своим быстрым движением и угрозой повышения уровня мирового океана.

**В географической теме** как раз и используются все возможности русского алфавита, и в паре Э — Е буква Э работает **по обычным правилам** письма: обозначает твердое произношение предыдущего согласного, а также не позволяет букве Е замещать себя после гласных (смягченный вариант звука Э не допускается).

Но именно при такой записи видно, что перед нами **ЧУЖАЯ РЕЧЬ, не наша, не русская.**

И тогда понимаешь, что права буквы Э **ограничены не зря.**

Comment: Шарон, не плэнер, а пленэр.

Comment: Да, извини, Артем за ошибку. Понимаешь, культурных людей вокруг мало, по-французски вообще никто не говорит, и художников знакомых нет. Ни литературных  тебе гостиных. ни великосветских приемов, как раньше-то бывало. Живешь как в лесу...

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за ответы. Вижу, что таких названий можно набрать как минимум несколько десятков, если поискать.

Answer (score 2):

В Эстонии много топонимов с "э" внутри, образованных, в основном, от *mägi, mäе* (мяги, мяэ; гора) и от *jõgi, jõе* (йыги, йыэ; река):
Силламяэ (Sillamäe), Нарва-Йыэсуу (Narva-Jõesuu), Сауэ (Saue), Муствеэ (Mustvee) — города;
Ласнамяэ (Lasnamäe), Мустамяэ (Mustamäe) — районы Таллинна;
Куремяэ (Kuremäe), Эмумяэ (Emumäe), Вескимяэ (Veskimäe), Келламяэ (Kellamäe) — деревни;
Аэгвийду (Aegviidu), Мяэтагузе (Mäetaguse) — поселки;
Аэгна (Aegna) — остров;
Вяэна (Vääna) — деревня, река;
Тырвайыэ (Tõrvajõe ) — деревня, водопад;
Сырвесяэр (Sõrve säär) — мыс.

Вот еще в вашу копилку: Кавагоэ, Мацуэ (Япония); Хюэ (Вьетнам); Чинхэгу (или Чинхэ, Южная Корея); Чандэ, Чэндэ (Китай); Хуанхэ (река, Китай).

Дополнение
[Фаэтон](https://neuronus.com/solnechnaja-sistema/2005-samye-interesnye-gipotezy-o-planete-fajeton.html) — гипотетическая планета (астроним).
«Варгамяэ» — первая книга пенталогии А. Х. Таммсааре «Правда и справедливость». Так теперь называется хутор, в котором родился эстонский писатель.
«Звезда Кэц» — роман А. Р. Беляева (посвящен Константину Эдуардовичу Циолковскому).